# Correct way to dump yuv values after avcodec_decode_video2

Tags: ffmpeg

I am decoding H.265 raw data:

```
 avcodec_decode_video2(decoderCtx, pictYUV, &gotPicture, &packet)
```

After the call, the value for `pictYUV->format` is AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P as expected.

I dump raw yuv values to a file as follows:

```
fwrite(pictYUV->data[0], 1, w*h, f);
fwrite(pictYUV->data[2], 1, w*h/4, f);
fwrite(pictYUV->data[1], 1, w*h/4, f);
```

For an input size of 640x480, when the file is viewed (using ImageMagick display utility), the image is what was expected.

However, for an input size of 864x480, the image appears to be corrupted.

What is interesting is if I run pictYUV through sws_scale, and dump the resulting yuv output, the image appears to be fine.

```
sws_scale(swsCtx, pictYUV->data, pictYUV->linesize, 0, pictYUV->height,
  pictNewYUV->data, pictNewYUV->linesize);
```

All I need is yuv data. I am hoping I can avoid the extra call to sws_scale. Wondering what is it that I am missing. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dump raw yuv values to a file as follows:
>
> ```
> fwrite(pictYUV->data[0], 1, w*h, f);
> fwrite(pictYUV->data[2], 1, w*h/4, f);
> fwrite(pictYUV->data[1], 1, w*h/4, f);
> ```

Lines are padded, write each line (of size `w` for luma or `w/2` for chroma) and then increment the data pointer by `data->linesize[n]`, where `n` is the plane index:

```
static void writePlane(FILE *f, uint8_t *data, ptrdiff_t linesize,
                       int w, int h)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        fwrite(data, 1, w, f);
        data += linesize;
    }
}
```

And then write the planes using:

```
writePlane(f, pictYUV->data[0], pictYUV->linesize[0], w, h);
writePlane(f, pictYUV->data[1], pictYUV->linesize[1], w / 2, h / 2);
writePlane(f, pictYUV->data[2], pictYUV->linesize[2], w / 2, h / 2);
```

Comment: Duh. Now I feel stupid. Thank you very much for your help.